# How can I set environment variable for just one command in fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

In bash, I can do `EDITOR=vim crontab -e`. Can I get similar effect in Fish shell?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
begin; set -lx EDITOR vim; crontab -e; end
```

Comment: is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: oddly, this doesn't work for me.  I'm calling a ruby script, and ENV doesn't pick up the variable I'm setting: `set -lx date '12/04/2012'`

Comment: @Duke: It works for me. `begin; set -lx date '12/04/2012'; ruby -e 'puts ENV["date"]'; end`

Comment: In the meanwhile this has been answered in the Fish FAQ: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-single-env

Comment: And what that FAQ says is this: `env SOME_VAR=1 command`

Answer (score 92):

Don't see why this shouldn't work:
`env EDITOR=vim crontab -e`
That bypasses the shell completely.

Comment: This is so much easier. The only problem is that bypassing the shell disallows any custom fish commands, which are probably locked in your muscle memory.

Comment: I saw that in the docs too, but then why doesn't the following work?
`env SOME_VAR=1 echo $SOME_VAR`

Comment: never mind, i should have just looked it up:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938483/bash-specifying-environment-variables-for-echo-on-command-line

Answer (score 15):

That is from the [Documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-single-env)

```
SOME_VAR=1 command produces an error: Unknown command "SOME_VAR=1".
```

Use the env command.

```
env SOME_VAR=1 command
```

You can also declare a local variable in a block and that would not bypass the shell

```
begin
  set -lx SOME_VAR 1
  command
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting [version 3.1](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#syntax-changes-and-new-commands-1), you can use the same syntax used in bash (`EDITOR=vim crontab -e`).

PR introducing the feature:
https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/6287

Answer (score 2):

depending on a definition of `be` function, this can fail

```
begin
  set -lx RAILS_ENV staging
  be rails r "p ENV['RAILS_ENV']"
end
```

In order for it to work:

```
function be --description 'Runs bundle exec' --no-scope-shadowing
  bundle exec $argv
end
```

Please, see the explanation of [--no-scope-shadowing option](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function)

> -S or --no-scope-shadowing allows the function to access the variables of calling functions. Normally, any variables inside the function that
>   have the same name as variables from the calling function are
>   "shadowed", and their contents is independent of the calling function.